How do you access the source code for TradingView Libraries?
For example TradingView has published Libraries such as:
TradingView/ZigZag/7
However no Libraries can be found for TradingView here when filtering on "Libraries":
https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/tradingview/?script_type=libraries&script_access=all
I have searched the Pine User Manual, Pinecoders and StackOverflow and I have not found an answer.
In addition to the above, in the Pine Editor, when you go to "Open Built-in script...", it list only one Library called "RelativeValue" and no other Library scripts. When you select the "RelativeValue" Library script it does not open, nothing happens.

@user207421 why are you down voting, wanting to close this and changed my original question in to a misleading question? This is about actual Libraries and not the usual libraries of scripts.
All of the related questions offered by Stackoverflow are not related at all.

The way you are searching is not right. It is not a "user".
This is the account of TradingView. From there, you can go to Scripts and then filter by libraries. Then you can find the source code of ZigZag.


Thank you. I don't know what the other account is then. An impostor? Or the same account but filtering on Libraries is broken when you access it that way?
So when you see a Library name you know [username/LibraryName/VersionNumber] to find the source code for it you go to:
https://www.tradingview.com/u/username then the Scripts tab and filter by Libraries.

Speaking of broken, maybe @vitruvius work at TV? In the Pine Editor, when you go to "Open Built-in script...", it list only one Library called "RelativeValue" and no other Library scripts. When you select the "RelativeValue" Library script it does not open like it should, nothing happens. Something is broken.

I don't know how you ended up with that link. There is no /u/ in the link that you shared. Regarding the RelativeValue, I have forwarded it to the team. Thanks for the report.

RelativeValue has been removed from that list as it was not supposed to be there.
